# PHP preg_match returns false

Tags: php

In the following code why the PHP preg_match returns false?
note: I have read some older questions with the same title as my question but the context was different

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $str = "This is a test for PCRE.";
        $ptrn = "This";
        $preg_match_result_arr;
        $preg_match_result = preg_match($ptrn, $str, $preg_match_result_arr);

        if (1 === $preg_match_result)
        {
            echo "The pattern has matched in the string:<br/>".
                "the match is $preg_match_result_arr[0]<br/>";
        }   
        elseif (0 === $preg_match_result) 
        {
            echo "The pattern has not matched in the string:<br/>";
        }
        elseif (false === $preg_match_result)
        {
            echo "An error has occured in matching<br/>";
        }

        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the delimiters, your pattern should look like (`#` used but it can be something else):

```
$ptrn = "#This#";
```

Answer (score 4):

Your expression is not correct, it should be surrounded by delimiters like so.

```
$ptrn = '/This/';
```

Answer (score 2):

Give your pattern inside '/pattern/'

For Example:

```
$ptrn='/^This/'
```

Comment: This is not the same pattern he is searching for, it will only match 'This' at the start of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using 
[T-Regx](https://t-regx.com) that will throw exceptions for you and will **automatically delimiter** your pattern:

```
<?php
    try {
        pattern("This")
            ->match("This is a test for PCRE.")
            ->first(function (Match $match) {
                echo "The pattern has matched in the string:<br/>".
                     "the match is $match<br/>";
            });
    }
    catch (MatchPatternException $e)
    {
        echo "An error has occured in matching<br/>";
    }
```

or you could do

```
if (pattern("This")->matches("This is a test for PCRE.")) {
    echo "The pattern has matched in the string:<br/>";
}
else {
    echo "The pattern has not matched in the string:<br/>";
}
```